# Converting site from jQuery to React - toggling from component

Tags: jquery, reactjs, components

First time asking on SO, so I hope I'm doing it right.

*Very* recently took up React. I'm currently trying to convert an old site of mine into React.

The data is 444 markdown files that are loaded into an array of objects (front matter and content), containing information about various medical drugs. In the left hand side, I want a sidebar containing a list of all the names of the drugs, and when clicked it will then toggle a component displaying the actual contents of the markdown file corresponding to the clicked name.

You can see the jQuery-based site at http://farma.morsby.dk (it's in Danish, but the contents really don't matter). I'm stuck at how I would go about toggling the info box (middle) by clicking the name (left side navigation).

An image depicting the issue is here (we can disregard the right hand pane, I just added it for good measure as it's currently on the site and I would want it in the end):

[Page setup and component setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4yse.png) (sorry, can't post images [yet]).

Current setup is sort of like this:

`<Parent />` calls `<NavContainer />` and `<InfoContainer />`

`<NavContainer />` calls (amongst other components) `<NavItem />` which then displays the individual drug names.

`<InfoContainer />` calls `<InfoItem />` which then displays the individual info boxes. `<InfoItem />` should toggle on the corresponding`<NavItem />`´s onClick.

As I understand it, the `<NavContainer />` and `<InfoContainer />` need a common parent to communicate. But I can't really figure out what to pass down. For the navigation, I need all drugs. But for `<InfoContainer />`, should I pass down all drugs and some information about whether the individual box is displayed or not, or should I only pass down the currently toggled boxes? I could (I guess) hard code some states that I could then mutate, but I would prefer a more dynamic approach (if I added/removed/renamed a drug, I wouldn't need to change the code).

In jQuery, of course, it's trivial to toggle by ID for instance. Maybe I shouldn't use React for this type of app at all?

I'm not looking for exact code solutions to the problem but more a concept of how I would go about solving my problem – if this is even something React would be good at.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having components affect other components that aren't descendants of theirs is not easy in basic React and usually involves a common ancestor and a whole bunch of callbacks.  I [recently wrote an answer on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128909/6902543) which might give you a few ideas on how to move forward with your app in React

If I were you, I would look into a [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) (or Flux-like) implementation, such as [Redux](http://redux.js.org/), and have the `NavItem`s dispatch actions into the store to toggle the visible state of the `InfoItem`s who would in turn, use the store state to determine if they should be rendered or not (or perhaps `InfoContainer` would do this for all `InfoItem`s).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Just read a bit on Redux, and it seems to be able to solve my problem (and even rather easily so).

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible use case to pass the data between parent child.

> 1. Parent to Child

- Props -  pass props to the children
- Instance Methods - passing the function reference to child component using ref attribute  e.g. ref={(foo) => { this.foo = foo;
  }}  and call the child component from the parent  e.g.
  this.foo.myFunc()

> 2. Child to Parent

- Callback Functions - pass the function to the child component as a
  props and access it .
- Event Bubbling - bubble the event up to the parent and handle it.

> 3. Sibling to Sibling

- Parent Component - handle the action and event from sibling and pass it to other sibling using  "Child to parent" as mentioned in 1

> 4. Any to Any
>
>    - Context - use react context

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with Redux, though.